# Bootstrap Javascript dont Work in Firefox and Safari IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm working on an app which you can see here: http://coster.herokuapp.com/

When I use Firefox or Safari for iPhone, it does not work correctly. I'm using Google Polymer 1.0, Bootstrap 3, Skeleton and of course jQuery.

This is the error I receive in [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADhUm.png)

Comment: What all scripts, i.e js files you have included in your program? One of them must have malfunctioned, due to incorrect usage.

Comment: Im not able to regenerate the error, can you tell me the flow, to know when and where the error occurs??

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh, but work correctly on Google Chrome...

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh, When you click on a door, a modal window should appear, but not seen. Everything works properly on Chrome, but not Firefox.

Comment: I've fixed it, but not quite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I've fixed it, but not quite...

I fixed with this code:

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
        success: function (data) {
            (new Function('document', 'window', data))
                .call({}, wrap(document), wrap(window));
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
</script>
```

in this isue at Github: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/625